# Why use _IsUnused this way?

Tags: c++, stl

I'm looking at code of the /libstdc++-v3/include/bits/boost_concept_check.h and found one macro:

```
#define _IsUnused __attribute__ ((__unused__))
```

And the _IsUnused is used in this template:

```
  template <class _Tp>
  struct _SGIAssignableConcept 
  {
    void __constraints() { 
      _Tp __b _IsUnused(__a);   /// Does this line work?
```

Comment: This is an internal implementation file. It may or may not work differently from user code. Anyway, the question is a bit unclear. "Why use _IsUnused this way?" Do you have some other way of using it in mind? "Does this line work?" Well you compile your code and it isn't broken, so it looks like it does work somehow. Perhaps try writing your own program that uses this facility, and ask a question in terms of that program.

Comment: Seems could work under g++. Not working with gcc.

Comment: Just interesting on why define/use like this.

Comment: from the filename this file originated in [boost](https://www.boost.org/) which being cross platform would have had different definitions of `_IsUnused` for different compilers and compiler versions, when it was copied in to libstdc++ which only needs to support a single version of gcc they presumably removed the unused definitions